# Ignore files with a specific pattern in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I am trying to ignore filenames starting with `33266158I` since these files are empty and don't need any processing. I have just pasted the part where I am ignoring the file.

But this does not work and only file name `33266158I` is being ignored but not `33266158I1`.

```
  FILENAME_IGNORE='33266158I*'
  if [ $M_GID != $FILENAME_IGNORE ]; then  #Ignore Problematic GID,Temp Soln
```

Is this the correct way to ignore files which start with `33266158I1`

Answer (score 1):

#### `[`

You may know it or not, but let's make it clear: `[` is not a part of the `if` syntax. I mean `if [ …` behaves like `if true`, `if false` or `if any_command`, where `[`, `true`, `false` and `any_command` are commands. They return exit status and this is what matters to `if`.

Even if `[` is a builtin (and it is in Bash), it behaves like a regular command. There's even a standalone `[` executable (e.g. `/usr/bin/[`) because it's required by POSIX.

This means `[ foo != bar ]` is just a `[` command with few arguments. Yes, `]` is just an argument, it's not a delimiter or anything like that. The command named `[` just requires `]` to be its last argument (this way the code is more legible). There's an equivalent command `test` which is almost like an alias: `[ foo != bar ]` is equivalent to `test foo != bar`.

Your `[ $M_GID != $FILENAME_IGNORE ]` is parsed normally, variables get expanded. `$FILENAME_IGNORE` expands to `33266158I*` and then word splitting and filename generation occur ([because the variable was not double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)). Unquoted `$M_GID` is potentially harmful for the very same reasons.

I'm really surprised "only file name `33266158I` is being ignored but not `33266158I1`". If these two files are in the current working directory, `33266158I*` should expand to (at least) `33266158I 33266158I1` interpreted as two words. I would expect `[: too many arguments`.

Whatever happens, using an unquoted variable after `[` (or in general) is not a good practice.

If you quoted the variables (i.e. if you used `[ "$M_GID" != "$FILENAME_IGNORE" ]` then `$FILENAME_IGNORE` would expand to `33266158I*` without being expanded further. The whole command wouldn't do what you want though, because `!=` (or `=`) in `[` (or `test`) does not perform any pattern matching. In this case the asterisk in `33266158I*` is just a literal asterisk.

---

#### `[[`

In Bash there is `[[`. It's a relatively common mistake to think `[` and `[[` are equivalent, they are not. All tests you can do with `[` can be done with `[[` but not vice versa. Differences:

- `[[` can do more;
- `[[` is a keyword, it's integrated with the shell parser, it changes some rules, it's actually aware of variables and quotes between `[[` and `]]`;
- `[[` is not portable while `[` is.

In your case the important thing is `!=` in `[[` will treat its right hand side string as a pattern if wildcard characters in it are unquoted. **This snippet:**

```
[[ $M_GID != $FILENAME_IGNORE ]]
```

should do what you want. This is one of very few places in Bash where a variable (here `$M_GID`) *may* be unquoted and another variable (here `$FILENAME_IGNORE`) *should* be unquoted (I mean if you double-quote `$FILENAME_IGNORE` then its value will not be treated as a pattern). Only because `[[` is integrated with the shell parser.

In `[[`, the operators `=` and `!=` use globbing patterns (these with `?` and `*`) with no connection to actual files in the directory. There is also `=~`, it uses regular expressions (with `.` and `.*`).

---

#### `GLOBIGNORE`

If `$M_GID` in your code comes from a glob, like in

```
for M_GID in *; do
```

then to ignore some names *completely* (i.e. to make them not appear from the expansion of `$M_GID` at any iteration) you can use [`GLOBIGNORE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html):

> The `GLOBIGNORE` shell variable may be used to restrict the set of file names matching a pattern. If `GLOBIGNORE` is set, each matching file name that also matches one of the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE` is removed from the list of matches. […]

In your case:

```
GLOBIGNORE='33266158I*'
for M_GID in *; do
   …
```

Notes:

- See what [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) says about matching filenames beginning with a dot (`.`) and how `GLOBIGNORE` changes the default behavior.
- Don't forget to `unset GLOBIGNORE` before you perform another (unrelated) matching.